# How to unmarshall config entry header with Go Viper package?

Tags: go, viper-go

I have a configuration file that looks like the following:

```
apps: 
    customer1: 
      upload_path: "/opt/uploads/customer1"
      local_path: "/opt/ready/customer1"
      bucket: "b1"
    customer2: 
      upload_path: /opt/uploads/customer2
      local_path: opt/ready/customer2,
      bucket: "b2"
```

I am using Viper to load and read the configuration file.

I am unmarshalling the above config and mapping it to the following struct:

```
type AppConfig struct {
UploadPath string `mapstructure:"upload_path"`
LocalPath  string `mapstructure:"local_path"`
Bucket     string `mapstructure:"bucket"`
}

appconfigs []*AppConfig

viper.SetConfigName(configName)
viper.SetConfigType("yaml")
viper.AddConfigPath(".")
viper.UnmarshalKey("apps", &appconfigs)
```

The problem I am trying to solve is getting the entry header (ie customer1 and customer2) without having to have a redundant field in my config file and ending up with:

```
apps: 
    customer1:
      name: customer1
      upload_path: "/opt/uploads/customer1"
      local_path: "/opt/ready/customer1"
      bucket: "b1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration can be unmarshaled to a map:

```
var appconfigs map[string]*AppConfig

viper.UnmarshalKey("apps", &appconfigs)
```

You can get the names from the map key.

Comment: Thank you, the answer was right in my face and I did not see it.  I just had to grab the actual keys from the map.